# Breakpoint Sass: Or Queries for Multiple Breakpoints

Tags: media-queries, breakpoint-sass

I have a few breakpoints set:

```
$breakpoint-tiny : 0 767px;
$breakpoint-small : 768px 991px ;
$breakpoint-medium : 992px 1229px;
$breakpoint-large : 1230px;
```

I saw in the breakpoint docs

> You can also write OR media queries, allowing you to write multiple
>   different basic or compound media queries and have them apply if any
>   of the sets of queries match.

What I'd like to do is use these or queries to target multiple breakpoints when needed in my code. For example:

```
@include breakpoint($breakpoint-medium, $breakpoint-large){
   .mobile-navigation{display: none;}
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

You should pass one parameter (a list), instead of two.

Try this.

```
@include breakpoint(($breakpoint-medium, $breakpoint-large)) {
    .mobile-navigation{display: none;}
}
```

I've wrapped your comma separated variables with parentheses.
Now Sass will see them as a one list, instead of two parameters.

Comment: I tried this and it just picked one. It didn't correctly do both. I gave up and just wrote them out. :/

Answer (score 1):

There are no OR queries in compass breakpoints, in particular `@include breakpoint(($breakpoint-medium, $breakpoint-large))` fails with:

> WARNING: Responsive contexts are not available for `or` queries as which query to use is ambiguous. Please only use single context queries. Default context is used.

You can use OR queries with the plain css `@media` rules if you really need it.

The right solution is to not specify a max width for your breakpoints, only the min width. Then start writing your sites without breakpoints ("mobile first"). If layout needs to change at a certain width you `@include breakpoint($brk)` and change the layout for all widths larger than `$brk`. That way you never have to specify a list of intervals that the media query applies to.